# How to delete the document based on ObjectId (_id)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-shell

How do I write a MongoDB shell query that will return the documents for all objects created after a specific date?

Collections like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59918c9014450171039b7e1f"),
"cont_id" : "59918c9014450171039b7e1d",
"systemdate" : ISODate("2017-07-25T00:09:00.567Z"),
}

db.itemtable.count({"systemdate" : { $gte: ISODate("2017-07-25T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

Returns - 15210

```
db.itemtable.count({'_id': {'$gt' : ObjectId("59918c9014450171039b7e1f")}})
```

Returns - 987652

Thanks!
Bharathi

Comment: dont use cont({.....})    Use find({"systemdate" : { $gte: ISODate("2017-07-25T00:00:00.000Z")}})

Answer (score 0):

`db.itemtable.find({"systemdate" : { $gte: ISODate("2017-07-25T00:00:00.000Z")}}).count()` 
returns count of those documents.

If you want cursor to those documents, use just find `db.itemtable.find({"systemdate" : { $gte: ISODate("2017-07-25T00:00:00.000Z")}})`

Comment: thank you both!

We all know ObjectId contains the current timestamp along with someother details, any way to find out the ObjectId greater than (>) "some id", which list down the ObjectId's created after specific timestamp

`db.itemtable.count({'_id': {'$gt' : ObjectId("59918c9014450171039b7e1f")}})`

Comment: Take some time stamp as Unix timestamp `08/16/2017 @ 8:48am (UTC)` is 1502873284 what translates to 0x599406C4. Then you just ` db.data.find({_id:{$gt:ObjectId("599406c40000000000000000")}})`